# WMI - Reading windows RDP event logs

Tags: python, wmi, event-log, rdp

I want to read some eventlog files with python over wmi. actually I can read event logs like System, Application, Security, InternetExplorer, PowerShell. But I cant access the eventlog file for the remotedesktop.

Currently Python script:

[python_script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukIUm.png)

The function check_vnc_services works. My problem is, that I cant open the eventlog for remotedesktop. I also tried it with C# and C++. I cant access it:

[eventlog file that I will open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAaEr.png)

Also the WMI Code Generator didn't show me such microsoft files:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuuD1.png)

I hope that someone can told me how I can access this rpd event log file. Suddenly I think that I maybe using a wrong WMI?

Comment: Nobody has an idea?

Comment: Did you get the answer to this?